# Register and spawn_link in Erlang not working together

Tags: erlang

I have a process running on node2. Can I register this process using register/2 on node1? Basically I am trying to do this: 
register(process_name,  spawn_link(node2, module, function, [Arg1, Arg2]))

I get this error:
** exception error: bad argument
     in function  register/2
        called as register(process_name, <5902.92.0>)

When I register a process local to node1, this works perfectly fine. I could not find any documentation which prevents registration of processes of other nodes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it is well documented, and the expected behaviour as register() is for local process registration.
http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#register-2

> Failure: badarg if PidOrPort is not an existing, ***local*** process or port, [...]

If you want global registration across your cluster,  read http://erlang.org/doc/man/global.html
Note that if you use standard OTP behaviours, (gen_server, etc) most of the time you don't need to use the global module directly.